# Css and JS can i save them in amazon S3

Tags: javascript, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi just signed up to amazon s3, and I have uploaded images, my question is should I save css and js, files in s3 our can this cause some issues with the site

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3, but be careful of your bucket permissions and ideally use Cloudfront in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to serve your css and js files in a 'serverless' way is to store these files in S3 and have it served by CloudFront.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jstubblefield7939/serving-static-files-with-amazon-cloudfront-cdn-ccec91a985cd) to configure CloudFront to serve your static content from S3.

This will not only save you money (since every file served from CloudFront is going to be way cheaper than S3) but also going to serve data faster to your users since CloudFront is technically a CDN (Content Delivery Network).